# Recommendations for converting 2~7V to 5V?

Tags: voltage-regulator

I'm looking for a switching regulator chip (buck-boost, sepic, or other topology) to convert 2~7V input to 5V. I realize it's easier to have an input voltage range that's consistently higher or lower than the output, but this is what I need. It also needs to support 10W output (2A@5V), and I'm looking for a relatively low-cost solution with minimal external component count. Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accepting a Range of Input Voltage that Straddles Operating Voltage](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/23806/accepting-a-range-of-input-voltage-that-straddles-operating-voltage)

Comment: Although I guess that question was only asking about lower current.

Answer (score 4):

What volumes? 1 / 10/ 100 / 1000 / 10,000 ...?
 What would be a "good" cost?

Note that the 2V input is lower than almost anything will start from. If you can use the 5V output to power the IC for starting then 2V is not a problem. If not, then 2V can still be handled but it adds slight complexity.

---

Easiest "roll your own" solution using low cost controller ICs is probably SEPIC because you don't need synchronous switches and almost anything can handle the control function.

It should be possible to implement a SEPIC buck boost with an MC34063 (my favourite olde workhorse smps controller) with an IC cost of $US0.31/100, $US0.17/1000  and under 10 cents US in volume in Asia. Needs two inductors but has various advantages.

Here is a TI inverse SEPIC "Zeta converter buck-boost application note.

[LM5085 - Designing Non-Inverting Buck-Boost (Zeta) Converters with a Buck P-FET 
Controller](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva608/snva608.pdf)

There are numerous SEPIC converter app notes around.

Basic SEPIC converter - buck boost [from here](http://www.powerpulse.net/techPaper.php?paperID=153)

[image]

---

You can also do seamless buck boost if you don't mind voltage inversion using a single switch and a single inductor [from here](http://www.edn-europe.com/buckboostconverterschangewiththetimes+article+2201+Europe.html)

[image]

IF inversion is allowable then this is potentially an extremely low cost solution. A 74Cxx14 (hex CMOS Schmitt trigger) and a MOSFET and some glue parts and an inductor would probably suffice. Parts cost under $US1 in modest volume. Under $US0.50 maybe in volume in Asia. PCB etc extra.

---

OR buck boost without inversion using a single switch and a 2 coil inductor. The inductor can be 1:1 and may be able tp be a COTS part such as a two winding line filter on a ferrite "bead".

---

If you don't mind paying a few dollars for the IC and MOSFETs you can get buck-boost ICs that will swap between buck or boost as required using a two MOSFET switch pair in the input. This is easiest if price is not totally crucial.

- Fully integrated switch:

The LTC3440 is a superb device if its ratings meet your needs.
 **In your case it doesn't -** but this is a guide as to what can be achieved. [datasheet](http://cds.linear.com/docs/Datasheet/3440fb.pdf)

[image]
[Pricing - $2.91/100](http://search.digikey.com/us/en/products/LTC3440EMS/LTC3440EMS-ND/455912)

---

The ST L6910 costs $1/100 from Digikey and uses a quad of external  high/low MOSFETs so power can be whatever you wish.
  [L6910 datasheet](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/DATASHEET/CD00002524.pdf)

You could probably replace Q2 & Q4 with Schottky diodes at some loss of efficiency if desired (and in fact Q2 is already paralleled with a Schottky to handle the transition region.

[image]

---

Excellent You Tube tutorial [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MIYyGeLl128)
 By LT and selling their parts but well worth watching.

---

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a **buck-boost** regulator, which can cope with input voltages both above and below the output voltage. 2V is rather low, and you may find it hard to get parts which go that low. Linear has [this selection guide](http://www.linear.com/products/buck-boost_regulator), which shows the [LTC3112](http://cds.linear.com/docs/Datasheet/3112f.pdf) which works from 2.7V.

[image]

Comment: What does it mean the fact that the output is rated for 5V/2.5A , Vin>5V? That it can only supply that power for buck operation?

Comment: @clabacchio - I'm not quite sure, but the datasheet has a graph which shows 2A over the full input range.

Comment: Checked: G04 (should be the picture number but I'm not sure) gives the output current for the input voltage range...seems hard to output high current with low input voltages

Comment: @clabacchio - where do you see this G04? I only see unnumbered figures (very annoying if you need to reference them). Anyway, the graph I was referring to is on page 6, bottom right.

Comment: The figure number is liiiiiittle and in the bottom right of the figure; the page is 5, top left but looking again is for PWM mode; probably your figure (G21) is correct

Comment: $5.3 at a quantity of 100! Wow!

Comment: @abdullah - Yes, Linear has a wide range of products and excellent support, but they're by no means cheap :-(

Comment: Nice part but $5.04/100, $4.86/1000 + at Digikey :-(